# Why am i getting unknown for an ip address?

Tags: networking, network-interface, kvm, libvirt

The ip address shown is unknown
[image]

```
[msingh@localhost ~]$ sudo virsh  net-dumpxml default
<network connections='1'>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>b92bbc87-3cda-49ca-9f11-46d7741681cd</uuid>
  <forward mode='nat'>
    <nat>
      <port start='1024' end='65535'/>
    </nat>
  </forward>
  <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:c9:44:98'/>
  <ip address='192.168.122.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.122.2' end='192.168.122.254'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>

[msingh@localhost ~]$ sudo virsh  net-list
 Name                 State      Autostart     Persistent
----------------------------------------------------------
 default              active     yes           yes

[msingh@localhost ~]$ nmcli con
NAME               UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE 
JioFiber-6mrCc_5G  90d43fdd-07d7-434a-9d1c-aa9078f6d7b0  wifi      wlp3s0 
virbr0             cff7ff76-544c-4c7a-b67f-0f2177ce0c8a  bridge    virbr0 
vnet0              44563c1b-79aa-4669-a5a7-acacb0cede3d  tun       vnet0  

[msingh@localhost ~]$ ip a 
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:7c:3f:0f:46:d2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:12:03:9d:47:7a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.29.230/24 brd 192.168.29.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp3s0
       valid_lft 3176sec preferred_lft 3176sec
    inet6 2405:201:e011:900f:6225:d2f7:39bb:4598/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 3584sec preferred_lft 3584sec
    inet6 fe80::6083:68d6:97ff:100f/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
8: virbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:c9:44:98 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:c9:44:98 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
10: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:c9:44:98 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fec9:4498/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: I have/had the same problem. In my case, it works only with rtl8193